# Where do I go from here?

Tags: android, string, jsoup

I have this code here which should get the information I need to generate strings for each line of text on the TXT document but I am unsure where I have to go from here and whether my app is even getting the information. The strings it needs to generate will be going into a TextView just if that information is needed but I am very unsure where I go from here as I have no knowledge of Jsoup and have been told that this is the easiest way of getting the information from the lines of text into strings but I just need help on how to get it there. The code that is being used is below:

```
    public void updatebutton(View v){
    new SyncTask().execute();
    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Updating", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

private class SyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String>{

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        Document doc = null;
        String returnValue ="";
        String baseWebPage = "http://nowactivity.webs.com/teststring.txt";

        for(int i = 0; i< params.length; i++){
          try {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(
                baseWebPage)
                .get();
          } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
          }

          Log.i("DOC", "The line " + doc.toString());

        }

          return returnValue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try reading up on how to use jsoup here: http://jsoup.org/cookbook/ They give some great basic examples that can get you started.

Comment: I looked through the cookbook and unfortunately I didn't find anything I could use. The only time I will use Jsoup is for this specific use so it isn't really necessary for me (Sorry if it seems like i am being a little arrogant).

Comment: You're not being arrogant. You're just being unclear. We don't know what you're trying to do with the web site once you have its contents as you didn't put that in your question

Comment: I am trying to get the lines of text from the TXT file that is hosted online onto a TextView by the means of strings. It is so then I don't have to update the app to people everytime I have to change a few words and they can just press a button to update the strings manually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that when you run this code you get every line of `teststring.txt` printed in your logcat?

If that's the case, then you could change the return type of `SyncTask` from `String` to something like `ArrayList` or even a `String` array, then add each `doc.toString();` to that list using your `for` loop, then return it.

From there you can access that array of strings and populate your `TextView`s accordingly.

You could also use Jsoup to cache the text file locally on the user's SD card, then you could populate your `TextView`s from there without having to reconnect every time.

Edit: Instead of using Jsoup, try using this:

```
private class SyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String returnValue = "";    
        String u = "http://nowactivity.webs.com/teststring.txt";
        URL url;
        InputStream stream;
        InputStreamReader streamReader;
        BufferedReader reader;
        String str;

        try {
            System.out.println("Reading URL: " + u);
            url = new URL(u);
            stream = url.openStream();
            streamReader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
            reader = new BufferedReader(streamReader);

            do {
                str = reader.readLine();
                if (str != null)
                System.out.println(str);
            } while (str != null);

        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid URL");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("Can not connect");
        }

        return returnValue;
    }
}
```

That would also work inside an AsyncTask, with that you could create the same ArrayList and return it, instead of trying to use Jsoup.

Comment: In my logcat nothing gets printed to do with the text file actually. Would you like a log? What logcat would you like though, like info or verbose? I am unsure what one the textstring.txt would be printed on.

Comment: I think the issue here is that you are trying to use Jsoup which is an HTML parser to get raw text. You really should use just an `InputStreamReader` and a `BufferedReader` to parse the text from the file.

Comment: Would this go under the doInBackground method or would I have to do it slightly differently?

Comment: Yes, this code should work inside an `AsyncTask`'s doInBackground method.

Comment: I copied the code in but I got problems which I seem to have trouble fixing to do with Multiple markers at this line
 - Method breakpoint:MainActivity$SyncTask [entry] - doInBackground(Void...)
 - Syntax error, insert "}" to complete MethodBody
 - implements 
  android.os.AsyncTask<java.lang.String,java.lang.Void,java.lang.String>.doInBackground

Comment: Sorry about that, should be fixed now. Just rip all of the code out of the `readURL()` function and toss it into your AsyncTask.

Comment: I feel I may have done something wrong. Could you possibly put your code above in a AsyncTask class just so I can make sure I get this correct. I feel the return, progress, Result parts of the AsyncTask are not the correct usage for your code.

Comment: You sir, are magical! I have now got a readout of the lines of text in my logcat. Thank you so much. I have been trying for about 4 days to do this and finally it is outputting to logcat. I cannot thank you enough!